# Android: Send GPS position as long as the app is running

Tags: android, service, timer, gps

I need to send gps position every 5 minutes, as long as the app is running.

What I've done until now is:
Created a class that extends from Application and in the Application.OnCreate() method i schedule a timer that executes the gps sending every 5 minutes. During the time when the the gps tracking is active (not just when the position is sent but all the time the app is running) I want to show a notification in the status bar.

My question is: is it save to do this through a timer that is executed in the Application.OnCreate method or should I do this inside a service? And how can I stop the tracking as soon as the app is closed (meaning no activity is inside the app stack).

I hope it is clear what I need.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to send gps position in every 5 minutes? I think its better to to send position whenever there is a location change. Battery will drain less.

Comment: I only activate the gps every 5 minutes for like 30 seconds (until the accuracy is well enough) and then send this position and turn the gps tracking off again. This would be the best option to save battery, no?